# Best .NET3.5 based strategy for creating disconnected db application

Tags: c#, database, .net-3.5, ado.net

My requirements are:

Relatively small database: 25-30 tables with 4-5k rows in each.

4-5 users with their own copies of local database on their laptops. Sync when needed or at the end of the day.

Free solution, as am making this setup for a NFP ogranization.

I have been researching various options in last few days. At last I was thinking of narrowing to Datasets, while serializing them to XML, but it seems that it is not a good idea afterall (answers to my previous questions suggested that strongly.)

So my question now is what approach (database and the access tech.) should I take? I would like to use c# and an easy to use technology to access my database and sync it at the end of the day.

According to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fxztkff.aspx, MS suggests two different approaches. I am surprised to see that they have not mentioned LINQ here.

So group, what path do you recommend?

Thanks a lot for reading.

Comment: What infrastructure (if any) is already in place? Is a SQL Server already there?

Comment: Have you considered replication between SQL Server Express and SQL Server?

Answer (score 6):

Add -> New -> "Local Database Cache". This should provide all the sync you need (via ADO.NET Sync Framework), running (IIRC) by SQL CE by default, which is (I believe) free.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx).

> Introducing the Microsoft Sync
>   Framework – a comprehensive
>   synchronization platform enabling
>   collaboration and offline for
>   applications, services and devices
>   with support for any data type, any
>   data store, any transfer protocol, and
>   network topology.

Comment: Hi Sacha, thanks for answering. One question for you though, without any research on my part: Does Sync Framework support peer to peer sync for SQL SERVER CE db?

Comment: Yes, read this post for more informations. http://dotnet.org.za/calmyourself/archive/2009/04/02/sql-express-change-tracking-framework-part-2.aspx

Comment: Actually, Sacha, the link you are referring to: Doesn't it show a server-CE sync, rather than a peer-to-peer sync. Please excuse me, if I am wrong, I am new at this.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a SQL Server (Standard or higher) already in place, you can use SQL Server Replication Services to sync local copies of the database to either a SQL Express or SQL Server Compact instance on the user's machine (both of these are free).

For more information, [try here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx).

It sounds like you'd be looking at Merge replication scenario.

Comment: No Adam, there is absolutely no infra, so as to speak, in place already. We are using Foxpro as of now, and manually copy files around.. Very bad solution indeed... :) please do not judge me.

Comment: In that case, go with the Sync Framework that's described in sacha's answer. Good luck! No judgement here ;)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a pattern for this they call [Occasionally Connected Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384436.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

To the OP:

The one word of warning I will give you on the Sync framework front is upgrading a database schema throughout the versions.  I'm using it on a [project](http://www.dealprocessor.com/) that I'm developing now, and am starting the "2.0" specification, which I've decided to remove it for various reasons.

I would greatly suggest you take the time to thing through the idea of how you wish to handle schema changes as you progress, and decide if this is the way that you want to go.  For me, it was to get the system up and running, but now that I'm dealing with the nightmare, I'm falling victim to the NIH scenario.

My outlook for 2.0 is to continue to use SqlCE for the clients, and SQL Server 2008 for the COR... but to roll my own Sync Fx based on heavy usage of reflection and a set of "DTO" objects.

Comment: Since I was planning for a new project, I have changed my approach altogether. Instead of going with a RDBMS, I am using db4objects. It has db4o<->db4o replication built in.

Comment: Yes, and RBDMS's like SQL Server have replication as well.  The issue comes in when you are trying to deploy to a non-technical user that doesn't understand whether a kb is short for knowledge base or if it is referring to a kb of data.  I can't imagine having someone that is an office manager launch dealprocessor, and then provide them with a SQL Server manual to get the syncronization working for their team... just doesn't seem possible.