# Sync multiple client databases to a master SQL server database

Tags: sql-server, database

We have many sites (above 70, will grow going forward) which will need to work offline sometime (no internet, no network). So we need to install some sort of local lightweight databases to these computers for them to easily work offline. These databases will only have the tables that they need. They need to read and write the data to these databases daily offline.

We also have a master SQL Server 2008 database that needs to sync the data with the above client databases daily when they are back to network.

So the process would be something like: (table1 and table2 in client and master DB are the same structure)

• Client DB: export table1 to a file1 in the folder named "Client" from the shared network drive; then delete all of data from table1 and table2; then import data to table2 from a file2 in the folder named "Server" from the shared network drive.

• Master DB: export table2 data to a file2 in the folder named "Server" from the shared network drive; import table1 data from file1 which is in folder "Client" of the network drive.

So my questions are:

1. What kind of a lightweight database we should install for the client machines? SQL Server Express/CE/Lite or something else? So that we can sync the client database and master database easily.
2. How should we sync the client and master databases data daily automatically?  In other words, how can we implement the process above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: Maybe some good hints here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730347/best-net3-5-based-strategy-for-creating-disconnected-db-application

Comment: Thanks for the links. Unfortunately we already excluded that approach using sync framework. And also we don't want to use replication method. Is there any other approaches out there for us to use except that?

Comment: Try a linked server? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Comment: Linked server is a great suggestion. But we have more than 70 client databases, so if the master database has so many linked servers, is it going to cause performance issue for the master database while doing transaction between these databases?

Answer (score 0):

you can use navicat or DBSync tool. Then setup windows scheduler via navicat /DBSync.

It will sync database after a certain time interval. If no internet , sync will not work, but when internet come sync will complete